# Migrating the backend from MS Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007, backend, database-migration, upsizing

The requirement for the client is to convert the backend of the current application running on MS Access 2007 to SQL Server 2005.

For this I tried to create an `.adb` using an upsizing wizard.

The problems I face are

- Almost all complex queries are throwing error
- Is it really required to upsize queries?
- If so how to do, I have no clues whatsoever

How will the final application look like in the end? Where should be the queries kept? (a few say the queries are to be created as view or stored procedure in SQL Server). Nothing is getting into my mind and am feeling tensed .

Can anyone sum up whole process. What all to be migrated other than tables and how?

Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: [How to migrate from MS Access to SQL server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255371/how-to-migrate-from-ms-access-to-sql-server-2005)
[Migrating an Access data table to SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761955/migrating-an-access-data-table-to-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ODBC data source and keep all of your stuff as they are... As you know recent version of Microsoft Access no longer support access project files.  If you plan to update your MS Office then its best to use ODBC data source.  This would move your tables to SQL Server but keep everything else in Access and you would not need to change much

Answer (score 0):

@Bharath-   Bharath-

Phase-1
First Identify the Backend DBS to migrate.
How are the tables in each Backend DB created.
Are they one time creation or are imported on monthly bases.

Phase-2
Tools Needed - SQL Server , SSMA for raw migration of the Backend DB.
SSIS if the tables are created from the flatfiles.

Use SSMA manily for getting the Data Dictionary.
Then recreate the tables in the Dev environment.

Coming to queries. In MS Access they are jet based. You need to rewrite them in T-SQL. This is quite easy task if you are having good/moderate knowledge in SQL.

Create the queries of Access as Views and link them to the FrontEnd.

The main thing here is you have to make a plan and then approach each time you face a problem. There are lot of forums and people ready to help. This is how IT knowledge has grown. So let us know more information.